# ASP.NET Ajax Framework

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Is there an ASP.NET AJAX framework other than just using UpdatePanel & Friends or the ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit?

Currently I am using plain ICallbackEventHandler calls but it gets quite complicated a while as a lot of serialization needs to be done.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I have found out that the best way (for me) for handling Ajax in an ASP.NET Web forms application.

- ASP.NET AJAX Script services for all AJAX calls. Returns
  JSON for complex types
- jQuery for the GUI and for the Effects.

Works really nice, and I am in full control of the output.

Comment: I love jQuery, it's my new best friend

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://ajaxpatterns.org/DotNet_Ajax_Frameworks) is a list of different AJAX frameworks to use with ASP.NET.

We also used [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) for smaller tasks.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com) has a nice library of AJAX controls.

Answer (score 0):

The new ASP.NET MVC Framework (beta)?

Comment: That's not an AJAX framework, but I won't vote you down for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics is popular, but gets wonky when you actually have to debug a problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are *tons* of Ajax Frameworks for ASP.NET. Some of them are; [Anthem.NET](http://anthem-dot-net.sourceforge.net/), [Ra-Ajax](http://ra-ajax.org) (my project), [Gaia Ajax](http://gaiaware.net), [AjaxPro.NET](http://www.ajaxpro.info/) and probably hundreds of others. My personal favorite (shameless plug) is obvously Ra-Ajax since that's what I am working with. (founder of)

Have a look at [Ajax Calendar Starter-Kit](http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Viewport-Calendar-Starter-Kit.aspx) to see its capabilities...